# Does Euphoria language have a shell?

Tags: shell, ide, interpreter

I'm studying/learning Euphoria language because it seems the most adequate for a new project.
I'm used to test commands on the shell when writing Python and Scheme.
I have been trying to find a shell on OpenEuphoria without success.
The default interpreter, eui, always ask for a file to run.
I also tried WEE and RedyCode and didn't find any sign of a shell.
The question is the one in the title: Does Euphoria language has a shell?

P.S.: It also does not seem to be an [Euphoria language](http://openeuphoria.org/index.wc) group here, on Stack Overflow... I cannot even tag it. I suppose that I might not get an answer, but I'll try anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Euphoria language is pretty done right now. I loved it so much. But nowadays it looks like it has some fans but not enough to be considered a contemporary programming language. Sorry, but until it will be discovered again by masses, future is rather dark for it... And Phix as good as it looked didn't fired up the masses either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry.

I once made a start on one for [Phix](http://phix.x10.mx/) and just spent the last 10 minutes resurrecting that, so it is available on my machine, but not uploaded anywhere yet. However it is severely limited, one-shot fashion, eg you cannot declare a variable and then set it!

Probably best to discuss this further on the [Euphoria language forum](http://openeuphoria.org/forum/index.wc)